# Type annotation not working in pylance when code is refactored

Tags: python-3.x, type-hinting, pyright

```
class InfoProvider:

    brokerageInstance: typing.Optional[IInfoProvider] = None

    @classmethod
    def setBrokerageInstance(cls, brokerageInstance: IInfoProvider):
        """Set instance of brokerage

        Args:
            brokerageInstance (IInfoProvider): _description_
        """
        cls.brokerageInstance = brokerageInstance

    @classmethod
    def checkBrokerageInstanceExistence(cls):

        if cls.brokerageInstance is None:
            raise ValueError("")

    @classmethod
    def getExpiryList(cls, spotInst: SpotInstrument):
        """func to return expiry list of given spot

        Args:
            spotInst (SpotInstrument): spotInstrument

        Returns:
            List[datetime.date]: expiryList
        """
        # if cls.brokerageInstance is None:
        #     raise ValueError("")
        cls.checkBrokerageInstanceExistence()

        return cls.brokerageInstance.getExpiryList(spotInst)
```

[image]

In this we can see that even though we are raising Error with the checkBrokerageInstanceExistence function , pylance is not detecting the code inside the refactored function.

Comment: AFAIK, this kind of check is not possible. Better sticking to the `if` checks.

Comment: Why does this code "after refactoring" looks like Java mixed with bad documentation practices?..